# Unable to save on Azure blob

Tags: vb.net, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to write an xml contents into blob, code executes but nothing happens.

```vb
Dim connectionString As String = "Azure_Connection_String"
Dim containerName As String = "https://myazure.blob.core.windows.net/container_name"
Dim FileName As String = "/site/business/data.xml"
Dim blobServiceClient As BlobServiceClient = New BlobServiceClient(connectionString)
Dim containerClient As BlobContainerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName)
containerClient.CreateIfNotExists()
containerClient.SetAccessPolicy(PublicAccessType.BlobContainer)
Dim blobClient As BlobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(containerName  & FileName )
Dim memStream As New IO.MemoryStream(data) //data has xml string
Await blobClient.UploadAsync(memStream)
```

Tried following as well but no luck,

```vb
Using uploadFileStream = New IO.FileStream(path, IO.FileMode.Open, IO.FileAccess.Read)
     Await blobClient.UploadAsync(uploadFileStream, True)
End Using
```

Expectation is I should see an xml file in my container like,

> container_name/site/business/data.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Trying to write XML content into blob, code executes but nothing happens.

**I tried in my environment and got the below results:**

In my container, I have a file with the name **`test.xml`** with content like  below:

**Portal:**

[image]

Now, you can use the below code to write the content using vb.net.

**Code:**

```
Imports Azure.Storage.Blobs
Imports System.Text

Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim connectionString As String = "your-connection-string"
        Dim containerName As String = "test1"
        Dim FileName As String = "site/business/test.xml"
        Dim xmlData As String = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?><root><person><name>John Doe</name><age>30</age><email>john@example.com</email></person><person><name>Jane Smith</name><age>28</age><email>jane@example.com</email></person></root>"


        Dim blobServiceClient As BlobServiceClient = New BlobServiceClient(connectionString)
        Dim containerClient As BlobContainerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName)
        containerClient.CreateIfNotExists()
        containerClient.SetAccessPolicy(PublicAccessType.BlobContainer)

        Dim blobClient As BlobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(FileName)
        Dim xmlBytes As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlData)
        Dim memStream As New IO.MemoryStream(xmlBytes)
        blobClient.UploadAsync(memStream, True).Wait()
        Console.WriteLine("XML uploaded successfully.")

    End Sub

End Module
```

**Output:**

```
XML uploaded successfully.
```

[image]

**Portal:**

[image]